# Eclipse RCP Clear Button in Textinput

Tags: eclipse, components, rcp

I just started working on an eclipse RCP application in my company and search now for following component:

In the eclipse preference dialog is a text input field with a eraser which clears the text box (see image).

[image]

Is there a component in eclipse RCP which does exactly that? Or one where I can set an image in a text input field, so I can implement just the functionality.

Or have I to write my own component extending from Text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse does not offer such a component, so you will have to implement one yourself.

But I wouldn't extend `Text` for this. Simply create a `Composite` with `SWT.BORDER` style, and a `Text` and `Button` as children. If you don't give the `Text` a border, it looks like the button is within the text box. Instead of the `Button` you could use a `ToolBar` with a single `ToolItem`, both with the SWT.FLAT style. This will look much better than a regular button.

Answer (score 1):

```
Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.SEARCH | SWT.ICON_CANCEL);
```

This is present in Luna's API, don't know about older versions. You can check more here: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet309.java?view=co

Comment: Tried that in Mars, but it does absolutely nothing. Running the snippet, neither of the "search" fields display any icons inside them.